# VBA - Reference New Tab Element With No URL

Tags: html, vba, excel, web, web-scraping

So I am using VBA for Webscraping. In my first TAB I am populating areas and then clicking Submit.
This generates a new tab with an element that I need to click to export the data that I need. The problem is when I try to reference that new element ID , I get a few errors.

I know one solution would be to reference the new tab URL but I don't know what that URL will be until it opens. + the parameters do not show in the URL.

Here is code:

```
 Sub SearchBot()


Dim objIE As InternetExplorerMedium 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim objIE_1 As InternetExplorerMedium

Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "http..."

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("chkSalesOrder").Click
objIE.document.getElementById("chkWO").Click
objIE.document.getElementById("chkWOPartNumber").Click
objIE.document.getElementById("chkOperation").Click
objIE.document.getElementById("Submit1").Click

****NOW New tab opens with the populated search
and I am not sure how to move forward
```

I am not sure how to declare my new object for my new tab.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you know what the window title will be? Is there anything in the HTML that gives an indication on a re-direct URL? Can you share some source HTML?   Also,You may have more success with Selenium when it comes to switching to a new window.

Comment: QHarr, Yes I actually have the new tab URL Link, it is a generic one where the URL doesnt reflect specific parameters based on the search criteria. 
Any suggestions how to declare it ?

Comment: No, sorry, they are actually not incorporated into the URL. 
URL just stays the same generic URL.

Comment: Try using the developer tools in browser to examine what traffic is being sent during the re-direct.. there maybe something useful there.

Comment: QHarr Can you explain how to do that accurately? I have dev tool open, not sure where to look now

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXGB4tIRNgM Don't know how good that link is but shows you what I am talking about. Chrome is an easy browser to use to inspect traffic.

Comment: This is not the relevant post to describe it so I'm gonna delete it. However, If you describe the same creating a post I'll be there to upvote first @QHarr. It's really surprising I could not find the solution anywhere until I opened the tab and found the same incidentally.